# In datejs toString('h') is displaying 0 instead of 12 at midnight

Tags: javascript, datejs

The h format specifier in the [spec for datejs](https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/wiki/Format-Specifiers) is supposed to be a number from 1-12.

Date.today() should have a time of midnight.

```
console.log(Date.today().toString('h'))
```

This is returning 0 instead of 12.

```
console.log(Date.today().toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

This returns 2017-03-06 00:00:00 as I'd expect.

Comment: Maybe it's military time? On a 24h clock, midnight is 0h.

Comment: Good. And you're here because...?

Comment: The [spec for datejs Format Specifiers](https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/wiki/Format-Specifiers) says h should be a number from 1-12.

Comment: Okay, it does. So? It's still not obvious what you need from the community. if it is a bug in their library - there is an Issues tab on github where you post bugs.

Comment: I assume I'm using it incorrectly in some way. Looking to see if someone who's used datejs has run into this.

Comment: For me your sample returns `'12'`. https://jsbin.com/qepicebozu/edit?html,js,console. Can you post a link to a jsbin that reproduces your result?

Comment: Thanks @geoffrey.mcgill that was the issue!
The version of datejs I was using must have been bad. I'll start using that version.

Answer (score 0):

@geoffrey.mcgill lead me to the answer in the comments to the question.

The issue was that the version of datejs I was using was not working properly. When I included:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```

Then the hour was displayed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll fix the file version issue on the website.